# Regarding Aufenthaltserlaubnis German visa

Tags: working-visas, germany

I am having Aufenthaltstitel visa with Aufenthaltserlaubnis status the validity as mentioned on the visa is 16-08-2017. I worked at Germany for 9 months after that I came to India and stayed for more than 6 months.

Can I now enter Germany with the same permit?

Comment: In case of a permanent residence (Niederlassungstitel), the rule is that if you stay for 6 months out of the country, your PR would not be valid anymore. Since your case is regarding the Aufenthaltstitel, I would suggest that you get in touch with a German consulate in India or the Ausländerbehörde which issued your Aufenthaltstitel.